# How to TreeMap to Hashtable?

Tags: java

I need to sort a Hashtable by Key, so i use TreeMap. The problem is when i want to go back to Hashtable from TreeMap. Problem in case "O".
I need to know how to sort a Hashtable, but i use TreeMap. Probably it is a easy fix. Hope yours can help me.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   //Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
   Hashtable<String,String> Tabla=new Hashtable<>();
   Tabla.put("Ovidio", "Alto y flaco");
   Tabla.put("Alberto", "Bajo y reponedor");
   Tabla.put("Adrian", "Alto y portero");
   Tabla.put("Juan", "Bajo y flaco");

   String opc="";
   HshTableMenu p=new HshTableMenu();
   while(!opc.equals("S")){
      opc=p.menu();
      switch (opc){
          case "O": //Ordenar por clave
            Map<String, String> sortedMap = new TreeMap<String, String>(Tabla);
            Tabla=(Hashtable)sortedMap; //cant cast
            break;     
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you’re using `Hashtable` instead of `HashMap`?

Comment: Yes, my professor, this menu must be created with Hashtable (yes, i know, may be obsolete).

Comment: I see. Just wanted to make sure you knew!

Comment: So? I dont know to sort the Hashtable. Some tips to do it with no TreeMap, or how to cast TreeMap to Hashtable?

Comment: `Hashtable` has a constructor that accepts a `Map`.

Comment: Ok! Nice. Problem fixed. Thanks a lot to Logan and other guy who reedit my question.

Comment: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 0):

> I need to know how to sort a Hashtable

`Hashtable` cannot be sorted. `Hashtable` is a legacy collection which was replaced by Java 1.2 collections in 1998. I suggest you avoid it, better use `ConcurrentHashMap`. Or if you want the same degree of synchronization then you can use `Collections.synchronizedMap(new TreeMap<>())` - synchronized and sorted but but poor performance compared to `ConcurrentHashMap`.

If you still decide to use `Hashtable` then more memory-efficient and speed-efficient way is sorting through a list:

```
List<String> sortedKeys = Collections.list(tabla.keys());
Collections.sort(sortedKeys);
```

Then you can get sorted elements through iterator(or foreach loop - it's syntactic sugar for the same thing):

```
for (String key : sortedKeys) {
            String value = tabla.get(key);
            //...
}
```

Or if you want sort in your style:

```
Hashtable<String, String> tabla = new Hashtable<>();
TreeMap<String, String> sortedMap = new TreeMap<>(tabla);
```

and **to return to Hashtable**:

```
tabla.clear();
tabla.putAll(sortedMap); //reuse an already created object
```

or

```
tabla = new Hashtable<>(sortedMap); //create a new object
```